# UISlider works on iphone 5 but not in iphone 4s or 4

Tags: simulator, uislider

I have a issue , i'm using a UISlider, i have an array of pictures 4 or 5, i have four views , and each one goes up with animation, and
i can't slide in simulator but it works with iphone 5. When i tested this app it works fine with iphone 5 but not with iphone 4 or 4s

I have two actions with this slider
Code : 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
[self showSaveButton];


imgArrayDate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"date1.png"],
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dateDay.png"],
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dateWeek.png"],
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dateYear.png"],
                nil];
```

}
- (IBAction)sliderDateChanged:(id)sender {
    [sliderDate setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArrayDate objectAtIndex:dateSlider.value]]];

}

- (IBAction)clickDateButton:(id)sender {

  [dateView setHidden:NO];

  [sliderDate setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArrayDate objectAtIndex:0]]];

  [dateSlider setMaximumValue:3];

  self.imageV.alpha = 0.2;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
      [dateSlider setContinuous:NO];
      [dateView setCenter:CGPointMake([mainView center].x, [mainView center].y/2)];

  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];

}
when i 've finished dragging 
- (IBAction)hideSliderDate:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touchEvent = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

```
if (touchEvent.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded) {  
    [dateButton setBackgroundImage:sliderDate.image forState:normal];
    [dateView setHidden:YES];

}
```

}

I don't understand why i don't have control of this slider

Comment: Which iOS version do you have on the iPhone 4 and 4s? (plz format your code)